# Place actionbar tabs left aligned

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have two tabs in my ationbar.

I have styles defined like this in my styles.xml

in values

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

    <!-- Setting values in the default namespace affects API levels 7-13 -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_color1</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/white</item>
    <!-- <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/action_bar_color1</item> -->
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabBar">
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
</style>
```

and in values-14

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripLeft">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item> 
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

    <!-- Setting values in the android namespace affects API levels 14+ -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_color1</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/white</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/action_bar_color1</item> -->
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabBar">
    <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
</style>
```

But the tabs are not aligned to the left, it is aligned to center.
How to fix this?

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the next production Android release.

Comment: @CommonsWare :- How can I align tabs to the left? Can you please answer it if u know.

Comment: They may not even *be* tabs. Android will convert them into a `Spinner`, akin to list navigation (also deprecated in "L"), in some orientations and screen sizes.

Comment: @CommonsWare :- That is ok, but is it possible to make changes in the above xml and make tabs to the left for now.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to control that behavior -- it is up to the action bar implementation. That being said, I haven't gone looking for it either.

Comment: @James "But the tabs are not aligned to the left, it is aligned to center" do you want the text of tabs aligned to left or all of the tabs in actionBar tabBar?

Comment: @mmlooloo :- I want the tabs to be aligned to the left , not the text